# What is The Best Multi Auth Solution?

Tags: authentication, database-design, redundancy

Which is a better solution for multiple auth system ?

1. Two different tables (Assume Admins and Customers)
2. Same table and specify user type flag

Answer (score 0):

Same table with a flag, a user is a user while their role is merely an attribute.

That being said, you may find yourself wanting to separate other levels (like having two different sprocs to display certain information) if there are fundamental differences in other levels (e.g. an Admin has access to 1m rows for something a Customer has access to 5 rows for) otherwise you could have statistics lead to bad query plans.